# $.on("click", function() | does not click. Element is dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have a function that generates, what needs to be, a click-able check note. No problem with that, this is how the generated html code looks like.

```
<span class="edit">
   <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

Then I try to create another function so that I could manipulate another div. Problem is that it does not seem that the button is clicking.
This is how the function looks like:

```
$(".edit").on('click', function(){
    //function to edit tasks
        alert("The check was clicked.");
    });
```

Alert does not show up. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
    //function to edit tasks
    alert("The check was clicked.");
});
```

```js
var c = $('#c');
$('#add').on('click', function(){

c.append('<span class="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Hello</span>');

});

$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
        //function to edit tasks
        alert("The check was clicked.");
});
```

```css
div {
   margin-top:10px;
}
.edit {
   width:25px;
   height:25px;
   margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
   background:#000;
   color:#fff;
   padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: Why `event delegation` ?

Comment: @wow, OP mentioned that `.edit` is generated dynamically to the DOM. Let me know if I missed a bit of their problem.

Comment: Oh, I've missed the part about static ancestors. Need to be more attentive. But thank you! Ive been stuck with this since last year (sorry,but I had to do this).